# Count the occurrence words and tags in each row of dataframe?

Tags: python

I have a code that performs the Part of speech tagging using nltk and next, I am counting how many tags occurred in each row.

Example:
If I have a string input as:

```
A = [('car', 'NN'), ('bike', 'NN')]
```

I tried to write my own for loop as below as well:

```
def count_tags(input_col):
    tag_count = {}
    for word, tag in input_col:
        if tag in tag_count:
            tag_count[tag] += 1
        else:
            tag_count[tag] = 1
    return(tag_count)

print('tag count is: ', count_tags(hi))
```

which output the same as:

```
tag count is:  {'NN': 2}
```

Question:

I have a CSV file that contains strings in each row as like `A` example above:

```
print(df['tags'])

0    [('car', 'NN'), ('bike', 'NN')]
1    [('TV', 'NN'), ('access', 'JJ')
```

and when I load with panda and then tried to count the tags:

```
df['tag_count'] = df['tags'].map(count_tags)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

My expected output is:

```
ID  tags                              count
2   [('car', 'NN'), ('bike', 'NN')]   {'NN': 2}
4   [('TV', 'NN'), ('access', 'JJ')]  {'NN': 1, 'JJ': 1}
```

Comment: Please show your data and expected output as a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @CypherX I updated the question.

Comment: Can you explain why in the last line NN:2?

Comment: @Marat sorry, that was a typo. I fixed it. thankls

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

```py
# Using the dataframe df from the Dummy Data section
df2 = (df.tags.explode()
        .explode().groupby(level=0).value_counts()
        .to_frame().rename(columns={'tags': 'count'})
        .reset_index().rename(columns={'tags': 'tag'}) 
)
# Show all tags count
header = lambda s: f'\n{s}\n' + ''.join(['=']*len(s))
print(header('All Tags Count'))
print(df2)

target_tags = ['NN', 'JJ']
# Show target_tags count
result = df2.loc[df3.tag.str.contains('|'.join(target_tags))]
#print("\nTarget Tags Count\n")
print(header('Target Tags Count'))
print(result)
```

**Output**:

```
All Tags Count
==============
   ID   tag  count
0   2    NN      2
1   2  bike      1
2   2   car      1
3   4    JJ      1
4   4    NN      1
5   4    TV      1
6   4   pen      1

Target Tags Count
=================
   ID tag  count
0   2  NN      2
3   4  JJ      1
4   4  NN      1
```

### Dummy Data

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[2, [('car', 'NN'), ('bike', 'NN')]],
                   [4, [('TV', 'NN'), ('pen', 'JJ')]]], 
                  columns = ['ID', 'tags'])
df.set_index(["ID"], drop=False, inplace=True) # important prerequisite for the solution
print(df)

## Output: df
#
#     ID                     tags
# ID                             
# 2    2  [(car, NN), (bike, NN)]
# 4    4    [(TV, NN), (pen, JJ)]
```

Comment: @Bilgin Please take a look at the solution. Let me know if you have any questions.